# LUA select specific string in table

Tags: string, select, lua, lua-table

I have a problem to recover values from a LUA table.

Table (string):

```
table = {
key = "/get value0\n/get [opt1][opt2] value1\n/get [opt1][opt2][opt3][opt4] value2\n/get value3\n/get [opt1] value4",
},
```

is it possible to select "/get" and "value0" for the first line.
and "/get" and "value1 or 2 / 3 / 4" on all other lines ?

I think I have an idea for it to work, but easier to say than to do

- 1) Counts total number of "\n" and add one.
- 2) Select first "/" and first space.
- 3) Select last "]" if present or last space before value.
- 4) repeat the operation for each line.

result:

```
/get value0 
/get value1 
/get value2 
/get value3 
/get value4
```

Comment: You say the first code block is a table, but it does not have table syntax (i.e., curly braces `{}`). Is it a single string? That affects what the solution should be.

Comment: i edit the post for table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
s=[[
/get value0
/get [opt1][opt2] value1
/get [opt1][opt2][opt3][opt4] value2
/get value3
/get [opt1] value4
]]

for l in s:gmatch("(/.-)\n") do
    print((l:gsub("%b[]%s*","")))
end
```

It first spits the string into lines and then removes all strings in brackets optionally followed by spaces.

A simpler match is `l:gsub(" .* "," ")`, which will remove everything from the first space to the last.

If you want to split the resulting string, use this code:

```
for l in s:gmatch("(/.-)\n") do
    local var1, var2 = l:gsub(" .* "," "):match("(.*) (.*)$")
    print(var1, var2 )
end
```

Comment: this work :) but it possible to have the results in 2 variables.
var1 = /get and var2=value1 ?

Comment: work with no space, how to add support for space (%s) for var2
/get [opt1] this : is value
var 1 => /get
var 2 => this : is value

never understood this system
https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html